# I have problems with opening file in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

I assume I have a compilation problem, but I want to make sure that is not my fault.

I have compared my code with some other from a program that I made couple of days ago, and I literally couldn't find any difference.

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("gps.txt","r");

if (f == NULL){
    printf("Couldn't open the file.");
    return 0;
}
int i= 0;
int n;
while(fscanf(f,"%c %d %d %d %c %d %d %d %d %d %d",&gps[i].sirina,&gps[i].stepen,&gps[i].min,&gps[i].sek,&gps[i].duzina,&gps[i].s1,&gps[i].m1,&gps[i].sek1,&gps[i].visina,&gps[i].brzina,&gps[i].sateliti)==11)
    i++;

n = i;
printf("%d",gps[1].sek);
```

File informations:(25 55 22 N 123 213 123 S 25 23 2

123 123 123 N 234 25 53 S 123 5 1

12 41 3 N 12 5 13 S 1 2 4)

Result of this code is always 0 (this is just to check if I can continue doing my program). There are informations written in the file, I double checked that I saved it every time but still my program outputs 0. On the same code I wrote couple of days ago, outputs are okay, including the fact the file is same.

I would be happy to know is there is compiling problem or if there is a mistake in my code. Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking to read the content of a file, look into  `fread` function and not `fscanf`.

Comment: One possible problem is that the `fscanf` format begins with a `%c`. This format specifier does *not* skip leading white-space, like for example the newline ending the previous line. Add a leading space in the format string.

Comment: I assume you mean "the result of `fopen` is always 0". This means the file could not be found. You may need to add the path information.

Comment: Depending where the problem occurs, please [edit] your question with the file's contents or the code that wrote the file. And it would get you more willing visitors if you provide a [example]. Please take the [tour] ans learn [ask].

Comment: I should make a program where I should read from file, for example, the biggest number out of those all, so I have request to do that by loops. It is not just the pure reading, if you can understand me. @LouisDurand

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude stated in comment use leading space in fscanf, `fscanf(f," %c ...)` may solve.

Comment: What does `fscanf` actually return? That will give you a hint on where things go wrong. Also use debugger (or debug prints) to check what values are actually read. Are they read to correct variables in correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your input the string in the fscanf is wrong.
you use the following string:

```
%c %d %d %d %c %d %d %d %d %d %d"
```

this is example of input line:
25 55 22 N 123 213 123 S 25 23 2

you need the following string:

```
%d %d %d %[^A-Z] %c %d %d %d %[^A-Z] %c %d %d %d
```

based on the given example, you read 25,55,22 using %d.

then and you skipping spaces etc using `%[^A-Z]`, and then you read N or S using `%c`.
space is also a character, you need to pay attention to it.

Comment: True, but you need to store the result of `%[^A-Z]`, can't `%s` do the job instead of `%[^A-Z] %c` ?

Comment: i guess he wanted to get either north or south AKA N/S and not all of the spaces etc.
and by using %[^A-Z], you don't need to save it.